# Check any one of given words available in a string Java

Tags: java, string

Hello i am trying to implement one logic

1) I'll get multiple messages 
(ex message: 
Solution not working,
Missed something,
Message Failed,
Working as expected
)

2) I have list words (Not working,Missed,Failed)

I need to consider the messages only which contains **any one of the words**

have tried like string.contains(word1) || string.contains(word2) but there is n number of words.
Thank you

Comment: which have you tried? what are your efforts?

Comment: if the list words are limited i can go with that but there is n number of words

Comment: use for loop to check the equality for the entire list of words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete solution for your problem :

```
package com.sujit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareMessages{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Assume the messages as per you said
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.add("Solution not working");
        messages.add("Message Failed");
        messages.add("Missed something");
        messages.add("This message will be ignored");

        //Your standard list of words
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Not working");
        list.add("missed");
        list.add("failed");

        Integer count=0;
        String msg = null;  //this will store which message will be ignored
        for (String string : messages) {
            for(String standard : list) {
                if(string.toLowerCase().contains(standard.toLowerCase())){ //check if message if present in your standard list
                    count = 1;  //if it is present, Count becomes 1
                    if(count==1){
                        msg = null;
                        break;   // we can break the loop for current message to be checked with standard list if it is present
                    }
                }
                else{
                    count=0;   // if the message is not your standard, then count becomes 0
                    msg = string; 
                }
            }
        }
        if(count==0){
            System.out.println(msg);  //finally you can get which messages is wrong according to your standard list
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue while understanding my code

Comment: thank you can you share few more info like how i can call this list of words from property file. can i make all together by comma separate into a key ?

Comment: Sure. Just tell me,from where your messages are coming

Comment: that's one of the third party tool based on request it will send response  .. in future few more messages and  words may added...

Comment: So can I update the above code by writing a separate method that will check if message belongs to your standard set of words.